# how to create a rewrite rule in htaccess with dot or period

Tags: regex, .htaccess

here is my url:

**example.com/profile.php?username=name.name**

or

**example.com/profile.php?username=name**

i want to rewrite it on this way

**example.com/name**

or

**example.com/name.name**

here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^signin$ signin.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^messages$ messages.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^signout$ signout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings/ChangePassword$ change_password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings/RemoveAccount$ remove_account.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^message/([0-9]+)$ show_message.php?id=$1
```

i have tried to add this code to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it works correctly with this type of links

**example.com/name**

but when i tried to add dots to my links i have a problem, first this is my code to add dots or periods i have tried

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this code make the scrip work only for profile.php if i tried to go to somewhere else like messages **example.com/messages** or settings **example.com/settings** it gives me a 404 error, how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php



RewriteRule ^signup$ signup.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^signin$ signin.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^messages$ messages.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^signout$ signout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings$ settings.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings/ChangePassword$ change_password.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^settings/RemoveAccount$ remove_account.php [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^message/([0-9]+)$ show_message.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9_\.-]+)/? profile.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
```